# CSS property "will-change" changes font color (subpixel font rendering)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, font-rendering

I am using Bootstrap 4. But when opening the dropdown component the font color is slightly changed.

After looking for some color definitions which could be the problem (there aren't) I found something strange: when I disable the `transform` and the `will-change` property of the dropdown element, somehow the font-color is affected. See video here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xkhl4m6enwvdzcd/Video%20color%20bug.mov?dl=0

It's most noticeable in Google Chrome and on a Cinema Display (Video).

Also it seems the subpixel font rendering is affected: [see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYOEJ.png) . 
The fun thing: the font-color is rendered more accurately when it's off.

In Safari a font rendering issue also occurs ...

Any idea what is happening here?

(I can post a Code Pen, or see the id of it in the video.)

Comment: Code pen is https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mBjBvg

Comment: As far I know, `transform` and `will-change` can make the browser use GPU to render (instead of CPU), which is better for animation etc. But couldn't see a color changing in your examples. What do you mean by color changing? `color` property? How slightly is it changing?

Comment: The font color appearing different is a result of the absence of subpixel rendering, and subpixel rendering disappears because the element is rendered via separate composite layer (i.e. rendered om the GPU, as mentioned above). I don't know the way to "turn on" the subpixel rendering back for such element.

Comment: @giovannipds In the video look at the text in the box in bottom left corner. The blue is glowing when "will-change" is active. The video quality is not that good, but when viewed "live" on Chrome & Cinema Display its quite disturbing.

Comment: giovannipds and @ilya-streltsyn: Thanks for the explanation. At least now I know... Cheers! I also found out that on other displays it's almost not noticeable, only in a screenshot, where you can see the subpixel-rendering being off.

Comment: @anbecode you're welcome. Do not forget to accept [BoltClock's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46725330/842768) if we've already answered this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Ilya Streltsyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2533215/ilya-streltsyn) and [giovannipds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/842768/giovannipds) have mentioned in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46711870/css-property-will-change-changes-font-color-subpixel-font-rendering?noredirect=1#comment80372341_46711870) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46711870/css-property-will-change-changes-font-color-subpixel-font-rendering?noredirect=1#comment80373054_46711870), that's a normal side effect of alpha compositing (subpixel rendering), which is what the browser does as part of hardware-accelerated rendering (GPU) brought about by `will-change` and `transform`.